# What does con- in "conceptus" mean? How does it relate to "a thing conceived"?

Tags: etymology, prefix

[*Why Do Languages Change?* (2010)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521546931) by [R. L. Trask (1944-2004)](https://www.librarything.com/author/traskrl). p. 105.

> (Latin *conceptus* is literally ‘with-taking’)

1. Does the prefix [*con-*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/concept#etymonline_v_17307) truly mean “with” here?  But [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/concept#etymonline_v_17307) says that it's "probably an intensive prefix".
2. If *con-* does mean “with”, then how did “with-taking” semantically shift to mean **"(a thing) conceived"**?

> ## concept (n.)
>
> "a general notion, the immediate object of a thought," 1550s, from Medieval Latin *conceptum* "draft, abstract," in classical Latin **"(a thing) conceived,"** from *concep-*, past-participle stem of *concipere* "to take in and hold; become pregnant," from *con-*, here ***probably an intensive prefix*** (see [con-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/con-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)), + combining form of *capere* "to take," from PIE root [*kap-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*kap-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "to grasp." In some 16c. cases a refashioning of [conceit](https://www.etymonline.com/word/conceit?ref=etymonline_crossreference) (perhaps to avoid negative connotations that had begun to cling to that word).

Comment: Why did you link Trask *Why do language change*? What's there on page 105?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As typically with this kind of thing, it's good to look at the different meanings present already in classical Latin.
[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DC%3Aentry+group%3D78%3Aentry%3Dconceptus2) mention "collection, gathering" as a meaning of *conceptus*.
And that makes sense: *capere* means taking or capturing, *con-* adds togetherness.
Taking things together is gathering.

But that is not the only meaning.
It is not unusual to use *con-* as an intensifier — and indeed it is quite common in Latin to use various prefixes as intensifiers disregarding their literal meaning.
One of the meanings of *conceptus* is indeed "gathering", but that seems to be quite unrelated to what you are after.

It is useful to dig a little further within Latin.
The word *conceptus* is derived from [*concipere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=concipio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
Broadly, its meanings are variations on the theme of *capere*; see the linked L&S entry for more details.
One sense of capturing this verb is used for is understanding.
And it's not that far fetched: to grasp something mentally is much like taking hold of something physically, and this is reflected in many languages.
The meaning of *conceptus* you are asking about seems to be related to this meaning (II in L&S) of *concipere*.

Based on this, I would answer your questions as follows:

> Does the prefix *con-* truly mean “with” here? But Etymonline says that it's "probably an intensive prefix".

No, I would not interpret *con-* as "with".
Literal interpretation of Latin prefixes is often ill-advised, in part due to words changing meanings unpredictably in time.
It is indeed probably mostly about intensity.

> If *con-* does mean “with”, then how did “with-taking” semantically shift to mean "(a thing) conceived"?

The prefix is mostly an intensifier used to tone the verb *capere*, "to catch".
*Concipere* is used in the mental sense (among other senses), so that *concipere* can mean "to grasp", "to think of something".
From this verb one can then derive the fourth declension noun *conceptus*, "the process of *concipere*" or "conception".
One can also derive the second and first declension participle *conceptus*, "the [thing/person/other] that has been grasped".
This is very literally "a thing conceived", so the description you cite is quite accurate in that sense.

I hope it makes more sense now!

Comment: llmavirta: A verbal prefix, as well as an intensifier, can make the verb directional (towards someone/ something) therefore requiring a dative (indirect) object. In Q: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/12992/1982 prefix "ir" (an assimilated form of preverb "in") applied to "rideo" gives "irrideo". In "nisi mihi irrisisset, forsitan ei ignossem." the directional prefix "ir" requires a dative (indirect) object, "mihi".